# Google Data Studio unique text

Tags: text, unique, looker-studio

I'm creating a pivot table which has 2 fields, one names and another handling time of cases.
The problem is, when I'm selecting a date range, it will show me duplicate agent names.
For example if John has the highest handling time on Monday and also Tuesday, it will show me John twice with two different amounts.

How can i show John only once with his average handling time for the date range that I'm selecting?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a table rather than a pivot.

Your dimension being agent name and metric being average handling time